# Forcing the removal of query string on a rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I find I'm the only one coming up with bizarre behavior on my website. Now one of my extremely important links has malfunctioned.

This is the RewriteRule I have that malfunctioned:

```
RewriteRule ^m/?$ /x.php?MOBILEMODE=m&MAIN=1 [NC,L]
```

I then test my URLs http://example.com/m and http://example.com/m/ in CURL. http://example.com/m/ is processed correctly, but http://example.com/m takes me to a redirection page. In HTML source code, its this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://example.com/m/?MOBILEMODE=m&amp;MAIN=1">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

I'm using apache 2.2.

Is there a simple way to fix this so that http://example.com/m and http://example.com/m/ provide the expected result (of running the x.php script) instead of receiving a redirection message from apache?

I thought adding `/?` after m makes the slash optional and I thought this problem would only be caused by including R=301 in the options, but I guess I'm missing something?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I found the answer I needed to my problem.

It turned out I also had a folder named m with the file robots.txt in it. I then removed that entire folder and now the RewriteRule works.

Comment: mod_dir (`DirectorySlash`) appends the slash to the physical directory _after_ your internal rewrite and triggers the external redirect. Instead of making the trailing slash optional, you could make it mandatory (since mod_dir would always add it). (Or delete the physical directory.)

Comment: Ok that just brought some crazy memories now when I was trying to make a multi-slash remover as an apache module and its the mod_dir module that delayed completion of the project because it always wanted to add an extra slash.

Comment: here's a vote for solving problem by yourself ;)